# Checking if a user is a member of a specific facebook group (2016)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

It appears there was a big update to the facebook api a year ago and a lot of the info online is inaccurate because of it. I'm trying to create a website that provides additional function for members of a specific facebook group; if a user is not part of a specific group I don't want them in it. Some groups may have more than 5k users but if I have to settle for less, so be it. I'm using the php sdk and have successfully made an initial api call with general user information.

Administrators of the group WILL be able to log in, but apparently Facebook isn't approving the "user_groups" permission (?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171082/check-if-user-is-a-member-of-a-specific-group-using-facebooks-javascript-sdk
I found this but I'm not sure how to make it work. [Facebook Graph - Possible To Check If A User Is A Member Of A Group w/o user_groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378318/facebook-graph-possible-to-check-if-a-user-is-a-member-of-a-group-w-o-user-gro) 
I'm using the graph api explorer and I can get a partial list of the groups I'm in but it's nowhere near complete (it displays 4 out of like 20). My thought was that if I can get a full list of members in a group that I could just do an [if user is in userlist then]

What would you do here?

Comment: If the group have less than 5k the admin can give user_managed_groups and then you get all members using that access token

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is no way to do this without some caveat where it won't work (when you have more then 5k members).  It also causes you to create a copy of the members list, instead of when a user wants to access the group.